# Can't load properties file for log4j 2 from path on disk

Tags: java, web.xml, log4j2

For my application in Glassfish 4.1.1 I'm configuring path to properties file in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>file:///G:/log4j2.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My properties file:

```
name=LoggingProperties
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/propertieslogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=com.ax
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Whenever I will put my file it is always showing: `ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration`

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks correct but please make sure to add the `log4j-web-2.x.jar` module to your classpath. (This contains the logic for reading the configuration location from the web.xml.)

Comment: I've already added it and also core and api modules in maven pom file.

Comment: Properties are loaded when file is in EJB resource folder. Unfortunately I need to access that file from outside of EAR file.